# How to Display first 9 images in UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a image url plist with 50 image urls.Iam trying to display that in a UICollectionview but it getting too slow.Iam displaying 9 cells(images) at a time like 3x3 (3 rows and 3 columns)**.How can i display first 9 images at loading time and  next 9 images on next scrolling** .?is that possible? i tried SDWebImages for loading images ,Its not working for me.Please help me.

**CODE INSIDE collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: ()**
**the code inside comment take lots of time for loading image,that code is used for loading image from document directory if image is not there then i will display in one place holder image**

```
    cell = nil;

    cell = (GMMCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"test" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
     docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];



    NSString *path;
    BOOL isImageLoaded = YES;
```

/////////////////////PROBLEM CODE:TAKING TOO MUCH TIME TO LOAD IMAGE //////////////////////

```
  bookImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [[allbooksImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent]]];
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    if(bookImage == nil){
        isImageLoaded = NO;
    }
    if(!isImageLoaded){
        [[cell grid_image] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"App-icon-144x144.png"]];
   } else{

       [[cell grid_image] setImage:bookImage];





    }

    sharedManager.bookID=bookId;

return cell;
```

**This is  what iam expecting**

[image]

But iam getting like this ,
App Loading time Without any scroll (first image:3 columns are empty) 
[image]

App screen after first scroll (second image:last column displaying 2  images ,rest of the part still empty )
[image]

App screen after a long scroll (third image: last colum some images are there ,rest of the columns still empty)
[image]

App screen again scroll to top,so the first image changed
[image]

Comment: How exactly SDWebImage not working for you? Show your code.

Comment: Are you downloading those images by yourself?

Comment: yes  check my updated question for downloading images

Comment: why are you using "wait for 5 seconds"?

Comment: that downlaoding part is working fyn..but loading part is taking too much time

Comment: @KyrDunenkoff  it showing MAc o link error

Comment: Where are you calling the method to download images. It is fine you are using GCD to download images so main thread won't get blocked for image downloading, the main thread may get blocked for some other operations.

Comment: @Searching  am downloading images to doc dircetory and checking whther image is there or not in cellforitem() method? that checking causes all delay.

Comment: Then try with using background thread or separate thread to do that checking. Hope it may help you.

Comment: @Searching can you show me how to do that please,i dont knw about that?

Comment: @Searching PLEASE CHECK MY NEW COMMENTED CODE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too much time to load image from document directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185896/too-much-time-to-load-image-from-document-directory)

Comment: @LithuT.V what url you have posted, have you checked that url properly. There are no such question, then how are you saying it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Searching there was one ,but Lithu give one answer it not working at all so i have to delete that entire question

Comment: Ok. I apologize @LithuT.V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
[[cell grid_image] setImage:nil];

dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    bookImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [[allbooksImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (bookImage)
        {
            [[cell grid_image] setImage:bookImage];
        }
        else
        {
            [[cell grid_image] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"App-icon-144x144.png"]];
        }
    });

});
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: Its working fine ,but loading same images in several places why?

Comment: @Navi I've modified my answer now check once.

Comment: First one to create a queue, second one to add operation to that created queue and third one to update UI, because UI must be updated from main thread. So with third one we are returning back to main thread to update UI.

Comment: ok thanks for that answer, but here only my third column images are coming randomly,and each scrolling the images are over writting  so i can see one image is changed to several images

Comment: i need 3 x 3 grid view. here only last column is coming .

Comment: Ok. I'll check and will let you know.

Comment: I 'll attach screen shots

Comment: Ok. Thanks I'll check

Comment: i have uploaded some screen shots for you

Comment: :your coding is working   but one more doubt how can i cache images in this code

Comment: @Navi according to ur requirement I've done a sample project. If upload it into github can u check that? Just let me know I'll then upload it.

Comment: Pelase give that link

Comment: @Navi https://github.com/sanjitshaw-87/RemoteImageDownloader/archive/master.zip you can check this link

Comment: :Searching :Thanks alot,i have to work on it today night  And if possible i'll let you the final result today itself.Thanks you so much ...

Comment: Ok fine you can check that, Check the class RemoteImageDownloader there you will get the major stuffs to download and save into Documents directory.